# Calculation of max possible current load from voltage multiplier connected to PSU 12V rail

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, 12v, current-limiting, multiplier

today I found in a box a PSU with two 12V rails each delivering 17A (Fortron SAGA II 400W) and decided to step-up the voltage so can feed the DPS5020-USB DC-DC converter (rated at 60V/20A max output). What's the proper way to calculate maximum current load allowed through the voltage multiplier, knowing that 12V rails have fluctuating 12 Volts (11.95 to 12.25V)

Comment: Well, the first thing is to note that you your SAGA II says "400 W." Then the next thing to note is that your DPS5020 says "60 V at 20 A" and this computes to "1200 W." So there is already a likely problem of expectations here.

Comment: The answers to my question with this PSU will show enough extreme cases to beginners in EE. And yeah, it's obvious to expect even the newbies in EE to know what means `P = V * I`

Comment: I'll just stand by and watch, then.

Comment: Me too, question is valid (last half an year a lot of people asking me what PSU and variable DC-DC converter to combine together and how)

Answer (score 1):

Voltage and current can be multiplied, but power plows through.  You have 400W available.  Let's assume the DC-DC converter is 75% efficient; that means you have 300W available to the output.  At 60V, 300W is 5A.  Plug in the real efficiency and you'll get the right answer.  (Note that efficiency may vary depending on the amount of current you're drawing, and the value you're interested in is close to the 5A level.)

Answer (score 1):

Without specs or link to datasheet, your question lacks substance, research and technical skill, so let me help.

The DPS5020 is a Buck regulator like all the other DPS series,  so the input must be greater than output.   **Input = DC6-60V**  **Output= 5-50V 20Amax, 1kW max** also matches 50V @ 20A spec.   Your question is misleading 60V @ 20A.

Answer: two 12V @ 17A for a PC PSU will share grounds so non-isolated but ganged as 12V @ 34A can supply something like 5 @ 20A max only due to voltage drop and max current output so you only need one input as it has enough VxI=P power.

Input power is likely to be 15% more as I could not see efficiency curves, so this what to expect, but certain ranges may be more or less.

[My Ref](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32821185351.html?spm=2114.12010612.0.0.zD8BtI)

Comment: Lack of substance, research and technical skill in the question? Yep, that was the goal of the question - adding technically correct answers for the newbies, because a lot of them use their PC PSUs as lab PSU connecting similar DC-DC converters

Comment: And btw 60V/20A was in the documentation that came with the converter, not my fault - a table printed on the plastic box shows for DPS5020 0-60.00V instead of 0-50.00V as output